# Перестала работать функция IMAGE("<урл или адрес ячейки>"), отображающая изображение

Tags: google-spreadsheet

С сегодняшнего дня в гугл таблицах Перестала работать функция `=IMAGE(<урл или адрес ячейки>)`, отображающая изображение. Пробовал разные браузеры и смартфон на андроиде. Показывает пустую ячейку. 
Кто сталкивался с проблемой и кто знает решение?

Comment: проблема решилась на следующий день сама собой

Comment: Проблему решили благодаря вашему сообщению. Спасибо за репорт.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка на стороне Гугл.

Если присмотреться, то в логах браузера есть сообщение о том, что для получения ресурса текущему пользователю не хватает прав.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не публикуйте благодарность как ответ. Вместо этого проголосуйте за него, если он оказался полезным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/483210)

Comment: Ответ "Ошибка на стороне Гугл". Пожалуйста.